# Subscript Out of Range on a dynamic array

Tags: excel, vba

For reasons unbeknownst to me, I am getting an error on a dynamic array with in a macro. It keeps saying "Subscript out of range". But - here's the kicker - if I run the same macro again after the error is displayed, then it would not complain. Here is the piece of code that I have

Both the arrays (arrTemp and arrPBIs) are declared as in a separate module along with the rest of the variables:

```
Public arrPBIs() As Variant
Public arrTemp() As Variant
```

---

```
arrTemp = Worksheets("Prioritized PBIs Only").Range("B2:B6").Value
ReDim arrPBIs(UBound(arrTemp))
For iRw = 1 To UBound(arrTemp)
    If arrTemp(iRw, 1) <> "" Then
        x = x + 1
        arrPBIs(x) = arrTemp(iRw, 1)
    End If
Next iRw
ReDim Preserve arrPBIs(x)
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: works fine for me. Noticed that you do not use arrPBIs(0).

Comment: What's the value of x when it fails?

Comment: `.. in a separate module along with the rest of the variables:...` Have you declared `x` in the other module? If yes, then that is the reason I guess... Share the complete code in this procedure.

Comment: I'd guess you're not clearing `x` in between runs.  Pressing "stop" when it errors clears all your variables.

Comment: Tim - Bingo. You are spot on. The value of x is not getting cleared. I had to manually set it to zero after the array - arrPBIs(x) is re-dimensioned. But, I thought having declared the x as Public x as Integer in the other module, it is reinitialized upon every consecutive run? No?

Comment: Avoid using Public variables/objects unless and until it is absolutely necessary... In your example `Dim x as Long` in your above procedure would be enough.

Comment: Thanks, Siddharth. I will keep that in mind in the future. However, this array variable is supposed to be accessed across multiple sub-procedures and I thought I had to make it a Public var in order to achieve access across subs.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Not that you are saving any code lines. Declare them in every procedure else you will have to reset them in every procedure. Better to declare than reset...

Comment: Side Note: Fix the following lines: 1.) `ReDim arrPBIs(1 To UBound(arrTemp, 1))` ' element 0 is no longer in the array 2.) `If Not IsEmpty(arrTemp(iRw, 1)) Then` ' no run-time error if error value, 3.) `ReDim Preserve arrPBIs(1 To x)` ' element 0 is no longer in the array.

Comment: Thank you, Siddharth.

Comment: VBasic2008, will do! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a more general answer to using arrays in VBA and getting arrays from Excel into VBA the following code may be helpful.  You need to have the locals and immediate windows open when you run the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrayDemo()

    Dim VBAArray As Variant
    Dim ExcelArray As Variant
    Dim ExcelArray2D As Variant
    Dim TransposedExcelArray As Variant
    
    ' Excel is setup to have 10 to 50 step 10 in A1:A5
    ' and 100 to 500 step 100 in B1:B5
    VBAArray = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    ExcelArray = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5").Value
    ExcelArray2D = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B5").Value
    TransposedExcelArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5").Value)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print ExcelArray(1)    ' gives an error
    Debug.Print "Error was", Err.Number, Err.Description
    
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Debug.Print TransposedExcelArray(1)   ' works fine
    Debug.Print "Error was", Err.Number, Err.Description
    
    Dim myItem As Variant
    For Each myItem In ExcelArray2D
        Debug.Print myItem
    Next
        
   Stop ' Look in the locals window for how the arrays are setup
        
End Sub
```

Comment: I have to make the arrays dynamic because I do not know if I'd always have to read only 5 cells. There could be more.

Comment: The 5 cells is for demonstration purposes only.  The main objective is to understand the differences in what you get as a VBA array when you assign from within VBA vs getting information from Excel.  You'll notice that all the dim statements just declare variant.  No need to Variant() or predimensioning arrays.

Comment: Aha! I am learning new stuff everyday. I did not know that it could be declared as a variant without the "()". Awesome. Thanks for the education.